# Unable to upload to firebase database from html form

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, save

I'm struggling to figure out what's going wrong with my attempts to upload data to firebase with the below code, but data is not saving in firebase.
When i clicked submit nothing happens but success message comes
could somebody help me.

my java script code fbdb.js is

```
// xxxxxxxxxx Submitting data to firebase xxxxxxxxxx
function uploadata (){
        var jbid = document.getElementById('jobid');
        var orin = document.getElementById('ori');
        var recv = document.getElementById('recvdt');
        var requnby = document.getElementById('reqn');
        var wksrc = document.getElementById('wsrc');
        var wktyp = document.getElementById('wtyp');
        var furn = document.getElementById('fur');
        var custm = document.getElementById('cust');
        var strt = document.getElementById('stdt');
        var endd = document.getElementById('enddt');
        var remar = document.getElementById('rema'); 
        
            var database = firebase.database();
            var firebaseRef = database.ref();
            var userData = {
                job: jbid,
                daterec: recv,
                requn: requnby,
                cat: wksrc,
                comm: wktyp,
                equipment: furn,
                customer: custm,
                startdt: strt,
                enddt: endd,
                rmarks: remar
            }
            firebaseRef.child('todo').push(userData);
            swal(document.getElementById('jobid'));
            swal('Your data is successfully uploaded to server!',
            ).then((value) => {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    window.location.replace("./logpage.html");
                }, 1000)
            });
         };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <!-- Sweet Alert JavaScript -->
    <script src="../js/sweetalert2.js"></script>
    <!-- Nunito Google Font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Log Book | CamsFusion89</title>
</head>
<body class="bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mx-1">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 offset-lg-1 offset-md-1 text-center mt-5 pb-4 text-primary">
                <h1 class="h1">Daily Work Log Book & Planner</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 offset-lg-1 offset-md-1 bg-white shadow mb-5 border border-primary">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 p-4 bg-primary divCover">
                        <img src="../images/firebase_logo.png" alt="Firebase cover image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 p-lg-5 p-md-5 px-3 py-4">
                        <div id="logForm" method="post">
                            <h2 class="h2 text-center text-dark mb-3">Log Book Entry</h2>
                            <div class="item">
                            
    <!-- Data Entry Start -->   
    
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="jobid">Unique Job ID<span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="jobid" onblur=""placeholder="Unique Job ID">
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="orgi">Originator<span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span></label>
                                <br>
                                <input list="orgi" name="Originator" class="form-control" onblur=""placeholder="Originator">
                                    <datalist id="orgi">
                                        <option value="Nalini Ranjan Muduli">
                                        <option value="M V Narendra">
                                        <option value="Iswar Toppo">
                                    </datalist>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="recvdt">Date of Received<span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span></label>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="recvdt" onblur=""placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
                                <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="reqn">Requisition By<span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span></label>
                                <br>
                                <input list="reqn" name="Requisition" class="form-control" onblur=""placeholder="Requisition By">
                                    <datalist id="reqn">
                                        <option value="Department A">
                                        <option value="Department B">
                                        <option value="Department C">
                                        <option value="Department D">
                                        <option value="Department E">
                                    </datalist>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="wsrc">Work Source (Business Segment)<span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span></label>
                                <br>
                                <input list="wsrc" name="Work Source (Business Segment)" class="form-control" onblur=""placeholder="Work Source (Business Segment)">
                                    <datalist id="wsrc">
                                        <option value="Steel-Domestic">
                                        <option value="Steel-Export">
                                        <option value="Steel-GSB">
                                        <option value="Non Ferrous-Domestic">
                                        <option value="Non Ferrous-Export">
                                        <option value="Non Ferrous-GSB">
                                        <option value="Engineering">
                                        <option value="Miscellaneous">
                                    </datalist>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="wtyp">Work Type<span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span></label>
                                <br>
                                <input list="wtyp" name="Work Type" class="form-control" onblur=""placeholder="Work Type" >
                                    <datalist id="wtyp">
                                        <option value="New">
                                        <option value="Revision">
                                        <option value="Correction">
                                        <option value="Proposal">
                                    </datalist>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="fur">Furnace/Equipment<span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span></label>
                                <br>
                                <input list="fur" name="Furnace/Equipment" class="form-control" onblur=""placeholder="Furnace/Equipment">
                                    <datalist id="fur">
                                        <option value="Steel-Teeming Ladle">
                                        <option value="Hot Metal Ladle">
                                        <option value="Corex Ladle">
                                        <option value="BOF">
                                        <option value="EAF">
                                        <option value="AOD">
                                        <option value="RH Degasser">
                                        <option value="Snorkel">
                                        <option value="Slide Gate Mechanism">
                                        <option value="Torpedo Ladle Car">
                                        <option value="Brick Shape">
                                        <option value="Petro-Chemicals">
                                        <option value="Tap Hole">
                                    </datalist>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="cust">Customer Name<span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cust" onblur=""placeholder="Customer Name">
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="stdt">Started On<span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span></label>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="stdt" onblur=""placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
                                <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="enddt">End On<span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span></label>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="enddt" onblur=""placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
                                <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="rema">Remarks<span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span></label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="rema" rows="5" onblur=""placeholder="Remarks"></textarea>
                                
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block text-uppercase mb-3" onclick="uploadata()">
                                Submit<small></small></button>
                            </div>
                            
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block text-uppercase mb-3" onclick="gohome()">
                            Cancel & Go Back<small></small></button>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Firebase -->
    
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.4/firebase.js"></script>
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.3.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.3.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.1/firebase-database.js"></script>


<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCnBlyACmhW_mmr0tU5IITOtHWwU68LRYs",
    authDomain: "camsfusion89auth.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://camsfusion89auth.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "camsfusion89auth",
    storageBucket: "camsfusion89auth.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "629330978244",
    appId: "1:629330978244:web:235676b5e28b8c3f8bb091",
    measurementId: "G-PPYS5Y0TWP"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

</script>
    
    <!-- Custom JavaScript -->
    <script src="../js/fbdb.js"></script>
  

</body>
</html>
```

I'm struggling to figure out what's going wrong with my attempts to upload data to firebase with the below code, but data is not saving in firebase. When i clicked submit nothing happens but success message comes could somebody help me

Comment: Here, you are tryibg to upload an `HTMLelement` to firebase. In every var to upload add a `.value`. That will upload the value

Comment: "When i clicked submit nothing happens but success message comes" => Can you share the code of the submit button (+ corresponding form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing this answer, I've changed multiple things:

- Datalists do not return the value, the input does [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist).
- The `document.getElementById('ori').value;` was changed to `orgi`
- Got the `.value` from the elements
- Added `<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>` to be able to use `swal`

```js
// xxxxxxxxxx Submitting data to firebase xxxxxxxxxx
function uploadata (){
  var jbid = document.getElementById('jobid').value;
  var orin = document.getElementById('orgi').value;
  var recv = document.getElementById('recvdt').value;
  var requnby = document.getElementById('reqn').value;
  var wksrc = document.getElementById('wsrc').value;
  var wktyp = document.getElementById('wtyp').value;
  var furn = document.getElementById('fur').value;
  var custm = document.getElementById('cust').value;
  var strt = document.getElementById('stdt').value;
  var endd = document.getElementById('enddt').value;
  var remar = document.getElementById('rema').value; 

  var database = firebase.database();
  var firebaseRef = database.ref();
  var userData = {
      job: jbid,
      daterec: recv,
      requn: requnby,
      cat: wksrc,
      comm: wktyp,
      equipment: furn,
      customer: custm,
      startdt: strt,
      enddt: endd,
      rmarks: remar
  };
  console.log(userData);
  firebaseRef.child('todo').push(userData);
  swal(document.getElementById('jobid'));
  swal('Your data is successfully uploaded to server!',
  ).then((value) => {
      setTimeout(function(){
          window.location.replace("./logpage.html");
      }, 1000)
  });
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <!-- Sweet Alert JavaScript -->
    <script src="../js/sweetalert2.js"></script>
    <!-- Nunito Google Font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Log Book | CamsFusion89</title>
</head>
<body class="bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mx-1">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 offset-lg-1 offset-md-1 text-center mt-5 pb-4 text-primary">
                <h1 class="h1">Daily Work Log Book & Planner</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 offset-lg-1 offset-md-1 bg-white shadow mb-5 border border-primary">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 p-4 bg-primary divCover">
                        <img src="../images/firebase_logo.png" alt="Firebase cover image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 p-lg-5 p-md-5 px-3 py-4">
                        <div id="logForm" method="post">
                            <h2 class="h2 text-center text-dark mb-3">Log Book Entry</h2>
                            <div class="item">
                            
    <!-- Data Entry Start -->   
    
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="jobid">Unique Job ID<span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="jobid" onblur=""placeholder="Unique Job ID">
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="orgi">Originator<span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span></label>
                                <br>
                                <input list="orgi-list" id="orgi" name="Originator" class="form-control" onblur=""placeholder="Originator">
                                    <datalist id="orgi-list">
                                        <option value="Nalini Ranjan Muduli">
                                        <option value="M V Narendra">
                                        <option value="Iswar Toppo">
                                    </datalist>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="recvdt">Date of Received<span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span></label>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="recvdt" onblur=""placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
                                <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="reqn">Requisition By<span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span></label>
                                <br>
                                <input list="reqn-list" id="reqn" name="Requisition" class="form-control" onblur=""placeholder="Requisition By">
                                    <datalist id="reqn-list">
                                        <option value="Department A">
                                        <option value="Department B">
                                        <option value="Department C">
                                        <option value="Department D">
                                        <option value="Department E">
                                    </datalist>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="wsrc">Work Source (Business Segment)<span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span></label>
                                <br>
                                <input list="wsrc-list" id="wsrc" name="Work Source (Business Segment)" class="form-control" onblur=""placeholder="Work Source (Business Segment)">
                                    <datalist id="wsrc-list">
                                        <option value="Steel-Domestic">
                                        <option value="Steel-Export">
                                        <option value="Steel-GSB">
                                        <option value="Non Ferrous-Domestic">
                                        <option value="Non Ferrous-Export">
                                        <option value="Non Ferrous-GSB">
                                        <option value="Engineering">
                                        <option value="Miscellaneous">
                                    </datalist>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="wtyp">Work Type<span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span></label>
                                <br>
                                <input list="wtyp-list" id="wtyp" name="Work Type" class="form-control" onblur=""placeholder="Work Type" >
                                    <datalist id="wtyp-list">
                                        <option value="New">
                                        <option value="Revision">
                                        <option value="Correction">
                                        <option value="Proposal">
                                    </datalist>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="fur">Furnace/Equipment<span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span></label>
                                <br>
                                <input list="fur-list" id="fur" name="Furnace/Equipment" class="form-control" onblur=""placeholder="Furnace/Equipment">
                                    <datalist id="fur-list">
                                        <option value="Steel-Teeming Ladle">
                                        <option value="Hot Metal Ladle">
                                        <option value="Corex Ladle">
                                        <option value="BOF">
                                        <option value="EAF">
                                        <option value="AOD">
                                        <option value="RH Degasser">
                                        <option value="Snorkel">
                                        <option value="Slide Gate Mechanism">
                                        <option value="Torpedo Ladle Car">
                                        <option value="Brick Shape">
                                        <option value="Petro-Chemicals">
                                        <option value="Tap Hole">
                                    </datalist>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="cust">Customer Name<span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cust" onblur=""placeholder="Customer Name">
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="stdt">Started On<span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span></label>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="stdt" onblur=""placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
                                <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="enddt">End On<span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span></label>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="enddt" onblur=""placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">
                                <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="rema">Remarks<span class="text-danger ml-1">*</span></label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="rema" rows="5" onblur=""placeholder="Remarks"></textarea>
                                
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block text-uppercase mb-3" onclick="uploadata()">
                                Submit<small></small></button>
                            </div>
                            
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block text-uppercase mb-3" onclick="gohome()">
                            Cancel & Go Back<small></small></button>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Firebase -->
    
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.4/firebase.js"></script>
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.3.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.3.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.1/firebase-database.js"></script>


<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCnBlyACmhW_mmr0tU5IITOtHWwU68LRYs",
    authDomain: "camsfusion89auth.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://camsfusion89auth.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "camsfusion89auth",
    storageBucket: "camsfusion89auth.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "629330978244",
    appId: "1:629330978244:web:235676b5e28b8c3f8bb091",
    measurementId: "G-PPYS5Y0TWP"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

</script>
    
    <!-- Custom JavaScript -->
    <script src="../js/fbdb.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>

  

</body>
</html>
```

Let me know how this goes.